# How to create a Tab Group in Google Chrome from the command line

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I use a script to open my browser and a bunch of tabs, for when I accidentally close the browser, with a small window still open in the background (SPAM windows, etc.).  The problem is, with Google Chrome set to continue where I left off, when I restart the computer, or Google Chrome, I just get a single windows open with the tab, not my pinned tabs, and tab groups.

Is there a way to create a tab group from the command line?

I have tried a few ways of doing this, but the scripting I can find, will only open the tab in the browser, not actually allow me to create a tab group.

I have tried using:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" google.com mysite.com`

This will load the pages as tabs, but I cannot create a tab group.

I have tried Python

`python -m webbrowser google.com mysite.com`

I cannot see anyway to create a tab group.

Comment: Any update on this? I have the same question

Comment: Nothing.  I simply added an entry in my script to open a localhost tab with #blank, and then after all my tabs are re-opened, I can multi-select the tabs and add them to a tab group then.

Comment: This is a crazy and bloated work around, which is to create a chrome extension. Make the extension access only a specific site, say "mysite.html"(stored as a local file), and then make the extension  open up multiple sites in a tab group (rather easily). As for the command line part, you can pass `start chrome mysite.html?youtube.com,google.com` and have the extension parse the url and open the specified sites. After that, simply have the extension close the `mysite.html` tab. You can even playaround with the url and develop a syntax for multiple tab groups and even different colors and names.

Comment: I thought about the extension route, but it does seem overkill currently.